# robocopy batch file is giving Error codes 2 and 3

Tags: batch, robocopy

I have a batch file to get robocopies of rar files from different places it used to work just fine but recently it is giving me error code 2 and 3 but the robocopy is working Fine I didn't even change anything in the batch file, it just suddenly started doing so

```
Net USE T: \\IP-Address\C$ Password /USER:hqadmin /PERSISTENT:YES 
if not errorlevel 1 set /A C0nnection_Success+=1 && echo "\\Connected Succesfully" >C:\LogSchoolXp.txt
if errorlevel 1 set /A C0nnection_Failed+=1 && echo "\\Failed To Connect" >>C:\LogSchoolXp.txt
psexec \\Ip-Address cmd /s /c "set path=D:\WinRAR\; && del c:\TempSchoolxp\*.* /s /q  && rar a -dh -ep1  c:\TempSchoolxp\XXX.rar c:\schoolxp\xxx.mdb"
timeout 5
robocopy \\IP-Address\c$\TempSchoolxp\ C:\backup\schoolxp\20\ /mov /NJS /NFL /NDL /NJH /nc /ns /np /r:2 /w:2 
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 set /A C0py_Success+=1 && echo "----- Done             Date: %date%   ------     Time: %time%" >>C:\LogSchoolXp.txt
if not %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 set /A C0py_Failed+=1 && set  Arr[0]= School && echo "----- Failed             Date: %date%   ------     Time: %time% ======= <<ERRORLEVEL IS EQUAL TO %ERRORLEVEL%>>" >>C:\LogSchoolXp.txt
NET USE T: /DELETE
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Recently it is giving me error code 2 and 3

These are warnings (and no error has occurred):

> The return code from Robocopy is a bitmap, defined as follows:
>
> ```
> Hex   Decimal  Meaning if set
>
> 0×00   0       No errors occurred, and no copying was done.
>                The source and destination directory trees are completely synchronized. 
>
> 0×01   1       One or more files were copied successfully (that is, new files have arrived).
>
> 0×02   2       Some Extra files or directories were detected. No files were copied
>                Examine the output log for details.
> ```

...

> These can be combined, giving a few extra exit codes:
>
> ```
> 0×03   3       (2+1) Some files were copied. Additional files were present. No failure was encountered.
> ```

...

You can change you batch file to only report real errors:

> **Any value greater than 7 indicates that there was at least one failure
>   during the copy operation**.
>
> You can use this in a batch file to report anomalies, as follows:
>
> ```
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 16 echo ***FATAL ERROR*** & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 15 echo OKCOPY + FAIL + MISMATCHES + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 14 echo FAIL + MISMATCHES + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 13 echo OKCOPY + FAIL + MISMATCHES & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 12 echo FAIL + MISMATCHES& goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 11 echo OKCOPY + FAIL + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 10 echo FAIL + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 9 echo OKCOPY + FAIL & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 8 echo FAIL & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 7 echo OKCOPY + MISMATCHES + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 6 echo MISMATCHES + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 5 echo OKCOPY + MISMATCHES & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 4 echo MISMATCHES & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 echo OKCOPY + XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 echo XTRA & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo OKCOPY & goto end
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo No Change & goto end
> :end
> ```

Source [Robocopy Exit Codes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, contrary to what the docs say, exit codes 0-7 do not reliably indicate success. See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs.de-de/issues/49.